# OpenLayers 3. How to transfer layer function

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have this code to add the ability to turn off layers

```
<input type="checkbox" id="road_check"  checked="checked" onchange = 'show_layer("road_check");'/>

function show_layer(cb) {
    cb = document.getElementById(cb);
    if (cb.checked) { 
        road_layer.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        road_layer.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

This works, but when I try to do

```
<input type="checkbox" id="road_check"  checked="checked" onchange = 'show_layer("road_check","road_layer");'/>

function show_layer(cb,layer) {
    cb = document.getElementById(cb);
    if (cb.checked) { 
        layer.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        layer.setVisible(false);
    }
}
```

it's not work. Where is the problem exactly?

Comment: you pass the `"road_layer"` as string and not as the layer itself. Try to remove the  double quotes and pass the layer object like so: `show_layer("road_check",road_layer);`.

Comment: Yes, it work, thanks